# pImpl idiom methods

Tags: c++, pimpl-idiom

I have implemented a basic pImpl set-up that is basically this example: [Is the pImpl idiom really used in practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972588/is-the-pimpl-idiom-really-used-in-practice).

Most pImple implementations I find online never show any method examples. The rule of thumb seems to be to hide all private members/methods in the pImple. The problem I am running into is I have a **public** method that looks sort of like this:

```
bool Foo::Bar(const void* data, size_t size)
{
    if( size > 0 )
    {
        if(data == nullptr)
            return false;

        size_t newSize = m_size + size;
        if ( newSize > m_capacity )
        {
            m_capacity = GROW_FACTOR*newSize;
            void* newMem = Malloc(m_capacity);

            if ( m_size > 0 )
                ::memcpy(newMem, m_data, m_size);

            if ( m_data )
                Free(m_data);

            m_data = (char*)newMem;
        }
        ::memcpy(m_data + m_size, data, size);
        m_size += size;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Should this be in the pImpl? If not it seems a bit ugly to put pImpl->member every few words. How do you go about this?

Comment: if you were using pimpl properly, the you'd simply call `pImpl->Bar()` in `Foo::Bar(...)`

Comment: That is what I am asking? So should this method be in the pImpl? Or am I misunderstanding something.

Comment: As I said, if you were doing it properly, yes it would. Your `Foo` class should only hold one member `pImpl`, and all public functions in `Foo` should call the methods in the implementation...

Comment: My thoughts are if you are using malloc and memcpy in a c++ program you probably should not be using pimpl.

Comment: I am not, the code is changed for stack overflow.

Comment: If you hate pImpl->bar so much, try wrapping it in a private method and call that wrapper everywhere.

Comment: @drescherjm My thoughts are if you are using malloc and memcpy in a c++ program you probably should not be using c++

Comment: @marsh can you clarify your question. Is `Foo` your public class? If so then "it seems a bit ugly to put pImpl->member every few words" doesn't make sense because your code sample does not actually put `pImpl->` anywhere so I don't see how it is working - `m_data` should be in the pImpl class.

Comment: You should not need to define any public functions in your PIMPL class: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24635255/is-it-possible-to-write-an-agile-pimpl-in-c/24638702#24638702

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I am interpreting your question correctly, i.e. that `Foo` is the public class and `Bar` is a public method. You have two options. Option A is:

```
void Foo::Bar()  // Foo is the public class
{
    pImpl->baz = 5;
}
```

and Option B is:

```
void Foo::Bar() { pImpl->Bar(); }
```

where the Impl class contains:

```
void Impl::Bar() { baz = 5; }
```

I'm not sure if there are any published guidelines on choosing between the two. In my own code I use Option A for simple methods and Option B once it starts getting to the stage that it seems like there are pimples everywhere.  It is a balance between redundant code and extra argument copying, and pimple abundance.

However, as suggested in comments, perhaps it would be cleaner to use Option B for everything, or at least every non-trivial function.