# Pimpl with std::unique_ptr in a derived class

Tags: c++, c++11, pimpl-idiom

I am failing to understand the following scenario. It is about using the pimpl idiom based on the `std::unique_ptr` in a derived class. Given a simple class hierarchy declared as follows:

```
class Foo
{
public:
  virtual ~Foo(); 
  //...
};

struct X;

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
  ~Bar();
  //...

private:
  std::unique_ptr<X> _d;
};
```

I am showing only code relevant for my question.

Imagine class `Foo` being some interface and the class 'Bar' which implements it. I want to use the pimpl idiom in `Bar`. Destructors are virtual and defined in the corresponding cpp files. Also the full definition of the `struct X`, which is only forward declared, is accessible in the cpp, so that for the destructor of `Bar` destructor `std::unique_ptr<X>::~unique_ptr()` can be instantiated. When I try to create an instance of `Bar`, I would expect it to work

```
int main()
{
  Bar b;
}
```

Instead, I get the compilation error **use of undefined type 'X'** followed by the message **can't delete an incomplete type** (in Visual Studio 2013 Update 2). However, if I explicitly add the default constructor to `Bar`, `main()` compiles/builds correctly.

```
class Foo
{
public:
  virtual ~Foo(); 
};

struct X;

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
  Bar();
  ~Bar();

private:
  std::unique_ptr<X> _d;
};
```

I am failing to see the correspondence between the presence of default constructors in this class hierarchy and the completeness of the `struct X` in the context of the `std::unique_ptr<X>` in `Bar`. Could someone explain or point to a possibly already existing explanation?

Comment: You actually need a destructor for Bar in a file where X is declared, only.

Comment: Side note, maybe see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24635255/is-it-possible-to-write-an-agile-pimpl-in-c/24638702#24638702

Comment: the "switch" is adding a constructor to `Bar`, adding one to `Foo` doesn't change a thing

Comment: I think your `std::unique_ptr` needs to point to your *interface* class (see my previous note).

Comment: @WorldSEnder Indeed, I have updated the post accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the default constructor added to `Bar` has to call `std::unique_ptr<X>`'s destructor in case `Bar`'s constructor throws an exception.

But `std::unique_ptr<X>::~unique_ptr()` calls the unique_ptr's Deleter: `std::default_delete<X>` - which requires `X` to be a complete type. [unique.ptr.single.dtor]

When you declare the constructor yourself, the instantiation doesn't happen because the constructor is only declared and thus linked at a later point in time and the compiler happily eats your code.

Comment: "But when instantiating std::unique_ptr<X>, the compiler also has to generate std::unique_ptr<X>::~unique_ptr()" -- This is, at least, sloppily worded. An implicit instantiation of a templated class does not lead to an instantiation of all its methods. The problem is really that Bar's destructor is generated for when the scope in which b resides is left. This in turn leads to an instantiation of unique_ptr's destructor. If "Bar b;" was replaced with the intentionally leaky "Bar *b = new Bar();", it would compile. (Don't do that, though.)

Comment: @ArneVogel, `Bar *b = new Bar()` does not compile: http://ideone.com/yFbE8V. The real problem is that sizeof(X) is static asserted, then? The method doesn't have to be instantiated.

Comment: @ArneVogel I found the real reason why all this happens. See the updated answer.

Comment: I noticed this too, but didn't understand it. Now it finally dawns on me (at least a bit): The constructor needs to be able to destroy the members in case an exception occurs during construction. Therefore, it is the implicitly generated c'tor, not the d'tor, of Bar, that requires unique_ptr's d'tor to be instantiated.