# pimpl, std::unique_ptr and constexpr constructor

Tags: c++, constexpr, unique-ptr, pimpl-idiom

I'm reviewing a non-compiling code where I find a design similar to this:

> B.h

```cpp
#include <memory>

class A;

class B {
   private:
    int val;
    // pImpl idiom
    std::unique_ptr<A> pImpl;
    constexpr B(int x): val(x){};
    virtual ~B();
};
```

destructor is defined in `B.cpp`, yet the constructor being `constexpr` it implies that it is defined within `B.h`.
But then compiling is failing because the compiler needs to have a constructor for `A`, which, at this point is an incomplete type.
Yet I think that, here, `constexpr` is a design error as I can't see how a `B` can be constructed at compile-time with an implementation.

**Thus, is `constexpr` erroneous in this context or is there a way to construct a `B` at compile time (I don't think that `std::unique_ptr` can be constructed at compile-time except from `nullptr`)?**

NB I tried to push the constructor definition inside `B.cpp` but the linker then (logically I think) triggered undefined reference on the constructor...
NB compilation has been tested only on msvc so far
NB I read a bunch of posts about pimpl and `unique_ptr` (which are numerous) but I might have missed an adequate one and the question is very possibly duplicate...

Comment: " (I don't think that std::unique_ptr can be constructed at compile-time except from nullptr" and thats what happens here. There is no initializer for `pImpl` hence the default constructor is called, which is indeed `constexpr`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number but in this case, why does the compiler is complaining that `A` is incomplete? Actually, he is trying to implement destructor for the ```std::unique_ptr``` though, in this constructor, it can be only a ```std::unique_ptr``` wrapping ```nullptr```?

Comment: One possibility is to create an interface class that `A` will inherit from. There is an example here, but the question is not a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24635255/is-it-possible-to-write-an-agile-pimpl-in-c/24638702#24638702

Comment: @Galik, though I validate Artyer answer, your proposal seems more natural. I include the interface, no forward declaration. Not sure, though, that it is possible in the actual code as I suspect also a circular reference... But from my sole wording above, your proposal is absolutely valid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not an issue with `constexpr`. When you construct members of a class, it needs the destructors of each member to be available, because if a succeeding member's constructor throws or the constructor body throws, the destructor will need to be called.

So you can't use `default_delete<A>` because the class is not complete. This is why the constructor is usually implemented in the source file with pimpl. The easiest fix is to use raw pointer `A* pImpl` and remember to delete it in the destructor. Or use a different deleter:

```cpp
class B {
   private:
    static void delete_a(A* p) noexcept;
    struct a_deleter {
        void operator()(A* p) const noexcept { delete_a(p); }
    };
    int val;
    // pImpl idiom
    std::unique_ptr<A, a_deleter> pImpl;
    constexpr B(int x): val(x){};
    virtual ~B() = default;
};
```

```cpp
// Source/implementation file

class A {
    // ...
};

void B::delete_a(A* p) noexcept {
    delete p;
}
```